# Library for waveform plotting

Tags: c++, qt, plot, waveform

I am looking for a library to plot the waveform and/or the spectrum of a real time recording. 
I'm using C/C++ and Qt 4.8.1 under Windows XP.

Audio sources come from 8 different microphones (may be more in the future), so I would like a fast-enough rendering to plot 8 waveform without too much delay. I'm using Portaudio to acquire the data. 
The tracks need not to be recorded, but I need to do some computation on them in real time. I know this may slow down things, so eventually I'd be happy also with a spectrum plot (...less expensive to draw?).

I tried to compile and run Qt's `Spectrum Analyzer` demo, but I found it pretty slow (around 1 sec of delay). I don't know if it's assumed to be that slow or I am missing something...

Searching the web I came across [MathGL](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/) but I'm not sure if it's well-suited for this purpose, maybe it's better to go for something more specific.

I would like to be as portable as possible but I definitely prefer ease of use rather than portability.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Recommendation Engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/166663).

Comment: Well, actually I'm neither asking opinion about which is better than which nor looking for something vague. I don't think my question is over broad. If you want you can read it as "How can I plot a waveform? These are my needs. I tried this and this with no luck." (which I don't think will be considered as asking for recommendation). However, if this is far from the spirit of SO then I agree to close.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/166663) either, so either way. :-P

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you very fast and lightweight simple framework:

[QCustomPlot](http://www.workslikeclockwork.com/index.php/components/qt-plotting-widget/)